# javascript number/currency formatting

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I am working with the following snippet and the end result is a number like `349`. How do I format it to be `$349.00`?  I thought `formatNumber()` would work?  What am I doing wrong? The javascript runs through a series of calculations and then presents Net Total, Tax and Total.  For Net Total and Tax I would like to see a $ and two decimal places.

Comment: @Bergi  64 Answers > 45 Answers on the question you are saying mine is a duplicate of.  I'd say my question and answer is better.  Mark that as duplicate.  This is the better answer/question.

Comment: @Bergi this question and answer is direct and simple and unique enough to stand on it's own and has provided help for over 3 years.  I'm not sure why the need to mark it as duplicate when the other question/answer is very generic.