# Hidden Inputs not Posting?

Tags: javascript, forms, post, paypal

Can someone tell me why all of a sudden some of my hidden inputs are not posting when I select a "No" option from one of 3 radio buttons on my checkout table?

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=O6ViKmJQRB

Heres my table...

```
            <table class="shop_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="product-name">Product</th>
                        <th class="product-total">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                                            <tr class="cart_item">
                                    <td class="product-name">
                                        <strong>Demo Vacation Home</strong><br /><br />1 adults, 0 children<br />2014-11-21 to 2014-11-23                                <strong class="product-quantity">&times; 1</strong>                                                            </td>
                                    <td class="product-total totalTextTop">
                                        <span class="amount">&#36;1,000.00</span>                                                           </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class="cart_item">
                                    <td class="product-name">

                                                                        Refundable Damage Deposit <span style="color: #ff0000;">(not taxed, not included in order total)</span>
                                                                                                         <br/><span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 10px;">Please note that the Refundable Damage Deposit must be paid within 45 days of your reserved vacation check-in date.<br/>For international creditcard transactions there is an additional 6% surcharge.</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product-total refundableDamageDepositTextTop">
                                        $<div id="priceDisplayRefundableDamageDeposit" class="priceDisplay">2,000.00</div>                          </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class="cart_item">
                                    <td class="product-name">
                                        Cleaning Fee
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product-total">                          
                                        $<div id="priceDisplayCleaningFee" class="priceDisplay">175.00</div>                            </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class="cart_item">
                                    <td class="product-name">
                                        City Occupancy Tax&nbsp;8%
                                                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product-total">                              
                                        $<div id="priceDisplayTaxRate" class="priceDisplay">80.00</div>                         </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class="cart_item">
                                    <td class="product-name">

                                        Preheat Pool?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="preheatPoolSelect" id="preheatPoolYes" value="yes" onclick='showFee("priceDisplayPoolHeating","200.00","poolHeatingFee")' checked><label for="preheatPoolYes">Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="preheatPoolSelect" id="preheatPoolNo" value="no" onclick='clearFee("priceDisplayPoolHeating","poolHeatingFee")'><label for="preheatPoolNo">No</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product-total">                          
                                        $<div id="priceDisplayPoolHeating" class="priceDisplay">200.00</div>                            </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class="cart_item">
                                    <td class="product-name">

                                        Have Pet(s)?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="havePetsSelect" id="havePetsYes" value="yes" onclick='showFee("priceDisplayPetFee","150.00","petFee")' checked><label for="havePetsYes">Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="havePetsSelect" id="havePetsNo" value="no" onclick='clearFee("priceDisplayPetFee","petFee")'><label for="havePetsNo">No</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product-total">                          
                                        $<div id="priceDisplayPetFee" class="priceDisplay">150.00</div>                         </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class="cart_item">
                                    <td class="product-name">

                                        Property Damage Protection?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="propertyDamageProtectionSelect" id="propertyDamageProtectionYes" value="yes" onclick='showFee("priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection","80.00","propertyDamageProtection")' checked><label for="propertyDamageProtectionYes">Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="propertyDamageProtectionSelect" id="propertyDamageProtectionNo" value="no" onclick='clearFee("priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection","propertyDamageProtection")'><label for="propertyDamageProtectionNo">No</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product-total">                          
                                        $<div id="priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection" class="priceDisplay">80.00</div>                            </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class="cart_item">
                                    <td class="product-name">
                                        Reservation Fee&nbsp;6%
                                                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product-total">
                                        $<div id="priceDisplayReservationFee" class="priceDisplay">101.10</div>                         </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class="cart_item">
                                    <td class="product-name">
                                        <strong>Vacation Package Total</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product-total">
                                                                    <strong>$<div id="priceDisplayVacationPackageTotal" class="priceDisplay">1,786.10</div></strong>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <!--
                                <tr class="cart_item">
                                    <td class="product-name">
                                        <span style="line-height:15px;">&nbsp;</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="product-total">

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                -->

                                        </tbody>

                <tfoot>
                    <!--
                    <tr class="cart-subtotal">
                        <th>Cart Subtotal</th>
                        <td>$1,356.10</td>
                    </tr>
                    -->





                    <tr class="order-total">
                        <th>Order Total</th>
                        <td>$<div id="priceDisplayVacationPackageGrandTotal" class="priceDisplay">1,786.10</div></td>
                    </tr>


                </tfoot>

            </table>
```

Heres the form with the hidden inputs...

```
            <form id='paypalCheckout' action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Demo Vacation Home" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="Demo-Vacation-Home" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1000" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1" />

            <!---
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_" value="Refundable Damage Deposit" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_" value="1" />
                        -->

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Cleaning Fee" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="Cleaning-Fee" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="175" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1" />

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="6% Reservation Fee" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_3" value="6%-Reservation-Fee" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="101.1" id="reservationFee"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_3" value="1" />

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_4" value="8% City Occupancy Tax" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_4" value="8%-City-Occupancy-Tax" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_4" value="80" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_4" value="1" />

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_5" value="Pool-heating Fee" class="poolHeatingFee"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_5" value="Pool-heating-Fee" class="poolHeatingFee"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_5" value="200" class="poolHeatingFee"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_5" value="1" class="poolHeatingFee"/>

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_6" value="Pet Fee" class="petFee"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_6" value="Pet-Fee" class="petFee"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_6" value="150" class="petFee"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_6" value="1" class="petFee"/>

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_7" value="Property Damage Protection" class="propertyDamageProtection"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_7" value="Property-Damage-Protection" class="propertyDamageProtection"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_7" value="80" class="propertyDamageProtection"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_7" value="1" class="propertyDamageProtection"/>


            <input type='hidden' name='business' value='juliocpreciado@gmail.com' />
            <input type='hidden' name='shopping_url' value='http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/cart/' />
            <input type='hidden' name='lc' value='en_US' />
            <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_cart' />
            <input type='hidden' name='charset' value='utf-8'>
            <input type='hidden' name='upload' value='1' />
            <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='2' />
            <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD' id='currency_code' />
            <input type='hidden' name='custom' value='|||' />
            <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/store/ipn/'>
            <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/thank-you/' />
            <input id='PayPalCheckoutButton' type='image' src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif' value='Checkout With PayPal' />

            </form>
```

And here's the javascript below that is the form...

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

            //money formatter from... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318674/javascript-number-currency-formatting
            Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(decPlaces, thouSeparator, decSeparator) {
                var n = this,
                    decPlaces = isNaN(decPlaces = Math.abs(decPlaces)) ? 2 : decPlaces,
                    decSeparator = decSeparator == undefined ? "." : decSeparator,
                    thouSeparator = thouSeparator == undefined ? "," : thouSeparator,
                    sign = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
                    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(decPlaces)) + "",
                    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
                return sign + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thouSeparator : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thouSeparator) + (decPlaces ? decSeparator + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(decPlaces).slice(2) : "");
            };



            function recalculateReservationFee() {

                var vacationRentalPrice = parseFloat(1000);
                var TaxRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceDisplayTaxRate").textContent);
                var CleaningFee = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceDisplayCleaningFee").textContent);

                var PoolHeating = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceDisplayPoolHeating").textContent);
                var PetFee = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceDisplayPetFee").textContent);
                var PropertyDamageProtection = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection").textContent);

                var reservationFeeTarget = vacationRentalPrice + TaxRate + CleaningFee + PoolHeating + PetFee + PropertyDamageProtection;
                var theNewReservationFee = parseFloat((6 * reservationFeeTarget) / 100);

                var formattedNewReservationFee = theNewReservationFee.formatMoney(2,',','.'); // example "$3,543.76"
                document.getElementById("priceDisplayReservationFee").innerHTML = formattedNewReservationFee;
                document.getElementById("reservationFee").value = formattedNewReservationFee;

                //document.write('<br/>The Vars: <br/>' + vacationRentalPrice + '<br/>' + CleaningFee + '<br/>' + TaxRate + '<br/>' + PoolHeating + '<br/>' + PetFee + '<br/>' + PropertyDamageProtection + '<br/>--<br/>' + reservationFeeTarget + '<br/>' + formattedNewReservationFee);


                function recalculateGrandTotal() {

                    var theGrandTotal = vacationRentalPrice + TaxRate + CleaningFee + PoolHeating + PetFee + PropertyDamageProtection + theNewReservationFee;

                    var formattedGrandTotal = theGrandTotal.formatMoney(2,',','.'); // example "$3,543.76"
                    document.getElementById("priceDisplayVacationPackageTotal").innerHTML = formattedGrandTotal;
                    document.getElementById("priceDisplayVacationPackageGrandTotal").innerHTML = formattedGrandTotal;

                }

                recalculateGrandTotal();

            }


            function clearFee(theNamedFee,theNamedClass){
            document.getElementById(theNamedFee).innerHTML = '0.00';

                var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(theNamedClass);
                for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    elems[i].disabled = true;
                }

                recalculateReservationFee();
            }

            function showFee(theNamedFee,someFee,theNamedClass){
            document.getElementById(theNamedFee).innerHTML = someFee;

                var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(theNamedClass);
                for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    elems[i].disabled = false;
                }

                recalculateReservationFee();

            }


            </script>
```

Comment: they are all hidden inputs. When I submit the form some of the values that are supposed to be posted are not. The only values that should not be posted are the hidden inputs that are disabled by clicking the "no" checkout button.

Comment: Are you using XHTML?

Comment: No. Just plain ol' html and Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more script which will one run on the button click .

```
<input id='PayPalCheckoutButton' type='image' src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif' onclick="javascript:doSubmit();" value='Checkout With PayPal' />
```

Script

```
<script>
function doSubmit(){
var j=1;
for (i =0; i<=27;i+=4)
{
 if(document.getElementById('paypalCheckout')[i].disabled==false)
{

document.getElementById('paypalCheckout')[i].name='item_name_'+(j);
document.getElementById('paypalCheckout')[i+1].name='item_number_'+(j);
document.getElementById('paypalCheckout')[i+2].name='amount_'+(j);
document.getElementById('paypalCheckout')[i+3].name='quantity_'+(j);
j++;
}

}
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: No... you don't understand... upon clearing the fee, the input should also be disabled so it shouldn't be included in the post. My problem was explained in more detail in one of my comments above. I know that the problem likely has to do with paypal wanting the item numbers to be given to them in sequential order. So, for example... if item number 1,2 and 4 are posted but 3 is missing, item number 4 will not get posted. I'm not sure if this is true but this is what i suspect is happening. I am currently reading the paypal html api for a solution.

Comment: So Eshan, this function is to enable all inputs onSubmit?

Comment: This function will exclude all the inputs which were disabled by your script when user selects "No" and will give the correct sequence to the hidden inputs .( ie. if there is item 1,2 , 4, 5 then it will change it to 1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: I am quite thoroughly impressed! I was in no rush to patch your code in because it was such few lines of code and looks so simple that I thought that it couldn't possibly be a fix for my problem but I was totally wrong. I can only aspire to be so good a coding some day. Thank you very very much Eshan!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your `clearFee` function. Making an Element `disabled` prevents it from being sent to the Server.

Comment: Yes, the clear fee function is working as it should. It disables the class that it passed to it as an argument.

Comment: If that class is one of your `input`s it will not post.

Comment: From what I see... if I disable an input by clicking the "no" radio button, the subsequent inputs are also disabled. For example, if I click "no" for "preheat pool", then "have pets" and "property damage" will also be disabled. if I click "no" for "have pets" the "property damage" will be disabled and not post. However, since "preheat pool" comes before "have pets" it will not be disabled. This is what I've observed by making multiple post and seeing which inputs get posted and which ones do not, based on which radio button was clicked as "no".