# Adding two digits after decimal - regex jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

right now i have this regex to return numbers with formatted digits.

```
function formatCurrency(amount) {
    var amt = ""+amount;
    return amt.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}
```

The result for any provided number is coming as Due: $1,944.5. 
But I need to add two digits after decimal i., it should come as Due: $1,944.50. Please help me with the correct regex to add two digits after decimal points. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Replace `(?<=\.\d)$` with `0`

Comment: And Replace `(?<=\.)$` with `00`

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript number/currency formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318674/javascript-number-currency-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just formatting the number to have 2 decimal places regex seems to be overkill you could just use the following:

`return amount.toFixed(2);`

unless there's a specific reason you absolutely have to use regex?

Comment: You're almost there. `parseFloat(possiblyAString).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the trailing zero with a regex, you can do it like this;

```
function formatCurrency(amount) {
    var amt = ""+amount;
    amt = amt.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    return amt.replace(/(\.\d{1})$/, "$1"+"0");
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lexogram/p8ryjss4/)

To ensure that there are always 2 figures after the decimal point, even when there are no cents, you can use `.toFixed(2)` before applying your regex.

```
function formatCurrency(amount) {
    // Ensures there are 2 decimal places
    var amt = parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2); 
    // Add commas for every block of 3 digits
    return amt.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lexogram/p8ryjss4/2/)

Comment: This works but if there is no decimal it does not adds two zeroes. Please help me to add two zeroes after a decimal if there is no digits after period.For example if I provide $1500 it should come as $1,500.00. Right now its coming as $1,500.

Comment: I've updated my answer, to show you how to integrate the '.toFixed(2)` technique with your own regex.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex for this operation.

```
function formatCurrency(amount) {
    return parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
}
```

Now, this will only work for western currencies.