# Format number in jsx React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am writing a jsx file and want to format the display of numbers in a table.  Here is the code for the table:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    {stringVar}
  </td>
  <td>
    {numberVar}
  </td>
</tr>
```

The numberVar is being printed directly; how can I display that number with C-style string formatting (I need to set precision value, add commas, and a $ character)?

Comment: This is just JavaScript -- so you can use anything that works in Javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318674/javascript-number-currency-formatting

Comment: I'm a big fan of using Mout (http://moutjs.com/docs/latest/) for this. It's not a library, just a collection of utility modules. See http://moutjs.com/docs/latest/number.html#currencyFormat and http://moutjs.com/docs/latest/number.html#enforcePrecision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any JS expression to format the value. A popular number formatting library is http://numeraljs.com/ but there are many others of course.

As for prefixing it with $, that's just string concatenation:

```
{"$" + numberVar}
```

Or, using [string interpolation](http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation) ES6 syntax :

```
{`$ ${numberVar}`}
```

Comment: numeraljs is not supported anymore and breaks with react native (I think because of babel). Use [numbrojs](http://numbrojs.com/) instead